# Tried/failed to replace null values with means in spark dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Update:I was wrong, the error stems from the vectorassembler, not the random forest, or it comes from both. But the error/issue is the same. When I use the df_noNulls dataframe in the vectorAssembler, it says it cannot vectorize the columns because there are null values.

I've looked at other answers for this question and liberated/borrowed/stolen the answer code to try to get this to work. My end goal is RF/GB/other ML modeling, which do not take kindly to null values.  I've put together the following code to pull all numeric columns, get each columns mean, then create a new dataframe that joins the two and replaces all the nulls with the mean. When I then try to create a vector of the numeric columns as the "features" part of the random forest, it returns an error that says "Values to assemble cannot be null".

```
val numCols = DF.schema.fields filter {
x => x.dataType match { 
  case x: org.apache.spark.sql.types.DoubleType => true
  case x: org.apache.spark.sql.types.IntegerType => true 
  case x: org.apache.spark.sql.types.LongType => true 
  case _ => false
   } 
  } map {x => x.name}
//NUMCOLS NOW IS AN ARRAY OF ALL NUMERIC COLUMN NAMES
val numDf = DF.select(numCols.map(col): _*)
//NUMDF IS A DATAFRAME OF ALL NUMERIC COLUMNS

val means = numDf.agg(numDf.columns.map(c => (c -> "avg")).toMap)
//CREATES A DATAFRAME OF MEANS OF ALL NUMERIC VARIABLES
means.persist()
//PERSIST TABLE 'MEANS' FOR JOINING  --BROADCAST ALSO WORKS BUT I WAS GETTING MEMORY ISSUES WITH IT SO I SWITCHED IT


val exprs = numDf.columns.map(c => coalesce(col(c), col(s"avg($c)")).alias(c))
//EXPRS CREATES FUNCTION TO REPLACE NULLS WITH MEANS

val df_noNulls = DF.crossJoin(means).select(exprs: _*)
```

df_noNulls should now be a dataframe of only the numeric columns with no null values, they having been replaced with the column nulls. Yet when trying to make a vector of all the values(minus the label/target) I get the "Values to assemble cannot be null" error.  I've attached a screenshot of the error in case that might help. It also says it failed to execute user defined function.[image: ERROR SCREENGRAB]

I know I've been asking a lot of questions about scala here recently, sorry about that, I'm just really trying to learn to do this. Below is the rest of the code to the RF step in case the mistake is there somewhere:

```
val num_feat = numCols.filter(! _.contains("call"))
val features=num_feat
val featureAssembler = new VectorAssembler().setInputCols(features).setOutputCol("features")
val reweight_vector = featureAssembler.transform(df_noNulls)
val rf50 = new RandomForestClassifier().setSeed(9).setLabelCol("call_ind").setFeaturesCol("features").setNumTrees(500).setMaxBins(100).fit(reweight_vector)
```

Comment: Your code seems to work as expected - perhaps the issue is elsewhere? Maybe in the way you "creat[e] a vector of all the values(minus the label/target)"?

Comment: I added the rest of the code and the error message in case that helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am *guessing* that the cause for this is a **column that is entirely null** - in that case, the average would be null too. To avoid that, you can simply add another "fallback" in the `coalesce` expression, using a literal 0 for example:

```
val exprs = numDf.columns.map(c => coalesce(col(c), col(s"avg($c)"), lit(0.0)).alias(c))
```

With the rest of the code unchaned, this should ensure none of the values in `df_noNulls` is null.

Comment: I feel like an absolute idiot. You are correct.  I know this is another question but now I'm going to make it my mission to find the best way to have scala return an array, list, etc that has column names where all values are null. I did describe() and I didn't see the counts as 0 for the column since it was buried in the middle of 500 odd columns. Thank you so much!